# How do you suppress the password prompts in expect scripts?

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I'm trying to write a set of scripts, a main payload script that runs some commands over `ssh` and a small `expect` wrapper that runs it. (For sake of argument, please accept that I can't put my `ssh` keys on my target machines.)

The `expect` script runs fine, filling in the password when required. However, it also passes the prompt (`user@machine's password:`) through to `stdout`. I want to remove *the matched prompts and only the matched prompts* from the output. I still want the results of the remote scripts running, so `log_user 0` is too broad.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not surround the expect for password with `log_user 0 ` and `log_user 1`?

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**.